# How to call a function of UICollectionViewCell class from ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit

How do I call UICollectionViewCell class function from ParentViewController button click?

Note: I don't want to make the function static.

```
class BasicInfoCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func abcd() {
        print("I'm called from parent view")
    }
}

class PersonalInfoVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBAction func updateUserInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        abcd()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call cell function. Try this Code. (Assuming Your button superview is your BasicInfoCell)

```
class PersonalInfoVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    @IBAction func updateUserInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {        
       guard let cell = sender.superview? as? BasicInfoCell else {
           retrun 
       }
        cell.abcd()
    }
   }
```